# How to simplify the following functional derivative?

Tags: functional-analysis, functional-calculus

I have to simplify the functional derivative:
 $$ \frac{\delta}{\delta f_{k}(\boldsymbol{x}',t)}\delta(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{\xi}(t))$$
where $\delta(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{\xi}(t))$ is a Dirac Delta function,  $\boldsymbol{\xi}(t)=[\xi(t)\;,\xi_{2}(t)\;,\ldots\;,\xi_{n}(t)]$ is a dynamical vector with n components and satisfies the equation $\frac{d\xi_{i}(t)}{dt}=v_{i}(\boldsymbol{\xi},t)+f_{i}(\boldsymbol{\xi},t)$.

Comment: In what context are you asking this question

Comment: In deriving the Fokker-Planck equation using the Furutsu-Novikov formula.

Comment: Would you be able to treat the delta function as limiting case of a box with with $a$ and height $1/a$ where $a \rightarrow 0$